# Brighten a section of a webpage background

Tags: javascript, html, css, png, brightness

Is there any way to have a semi-transparent overlay in a webpage and will brighten the underlying content? I'm wanting to have a dynamic content in the background of a transparent overlay with one section highlighted in a brighter than the rest of the background.

For example, in the mock-up below there is a graph in the background, overlaid by a dark black image, which, in turn, is overlaid by a lighter color on the right.

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5736/screenshot20091203at114.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5736/screenshot20091203at114.png)

Is such a thing possible using either Javascript, CSS, HTML, transparent PNGs, etc.?

Edit: maybe there is a way to use CSS opacity to have a partially transparent black layer, overlaid by a partially transparent white layer, giving the shades of grey, as in the example image (thanks for everyone's ideas so far).

Comment: No, just make the rest of it darker :P

Comment: Not sure if I can visualize what you are asking. Care to upload a photoshop mock-up?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the location of a DOM object, retrieve its size and overlay a set of DIVs creating a 'wall with a window' for your 'highlighted' area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent PNG atop another background to get this effect:

```
<div style="float: left; background-image:url(solid.jpg); width: 100%;">
 <div style="width: 300px; background-image:url(white-50-percent-opacity.png);">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo . . .
 </div>
</div>
```

Where `solid.jpg` is non-transparent background image and `white-50-percent-opacity.png` is a semi-transparent PNG.

Comment: Using CSS opacity has better rate of success than transparent PNG's, which do not work in IE6 by default. `filter: alpha(opacity=50)` on the other hand, does.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible with pure HTML + CSS in an relatively cross browser compatible way. You don't need to use PNG's, just put an element over your black bar which has white background and `opacity: 0.5`. For IE, supply also the `filter: alpha(opacity=50)` variant.

To easen up the positioning, set the black bar to position relative and then absolutely position the white overlay inside.

For example:

```
<label><span style="left: 50px; width: 100px;"></span></label>
```

And the CSS:

```
label {
    background: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```